# What's the most efficient way to logon in Windows?

Tags: c, security, winapi, authentication, windows-7

I've been looking for the most efficient way to authenticate user credentials in Windows. My operating system version I am using is Windows 7. I've looked at `LogonUser()`, but I only want to validate a local user without the expense of a network login. I've looked at some of the secur32.dll functions, but I'm unsure what functions I need to use to validate a plaintext username and password in that API. What method would allow me to implement a local login?

Comment: Where is this program running? Don't you have to be logged in before you can do anything else? Can you give a bit more context about your use case?

Comment: The program is running after you log in, I need it for a token in a user impersonation.